# UIUserInterfaceStyle reverting to UIUserInterfaceStyleDark on each reopen

Tags: tvos, tvos10, tvos11

I'm having the strangest issue with a tvOS app where I check `self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle` to setup my UI according to light or dark mode in tvOS 10+.

On initial launch, all works as expected, and with the system in Light mode, `UIUserInterfaceStyleLight` is returned. However, by backgrounding and foregrounding the app (going out to the Home screen and back), the app all of a sudden returns `UIUserInterfaceStyleDark`. This is without changing the system appearance and even validating the system appearance remains set to Light.

Strangely enough, if I set the system to Dark then on each relaunch it returns `UIUserInterfaceStyleLight`, yet on initial launch it will be the proper `UIUserInterfaceStyleDark`.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to replace an image depending if tvOS is in dark mode or light mode? I added the dark mode images and light mode images already but not sure if I need to programmatically add the images also. Here is a screenshot of what I found to do in the assets.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, removing my base-level UINavigationController completely fixed this. It makes no sense to me how having a simple (stock) UINavigationController could override the values being returned from the system for Light/Dark mode, but either way that was the fix.